# ShareLatex - Hyperref / hyperlink to included PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdf, sharelatex, hyperlink

I have used \includepdf for my appendicies but have some problems linking to them within the text. The codes for the appendices are at the bottom of my code provided below. I appologize if its a mess, but I am relativly new to this.

As you can see, I have labeled all of them in order to use hyperref, and it does work, exept of a small problem with the last one.

When referring to Appendix C, it takes me to the last page of the PDF (in this case, page 2. The two first appendices have only 1 page). However, from the table of contents it takes me to the first page. I have tried with hyperlink aswell, but no luck. How can I specify that it should jump to the first page?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,12 pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{floatrow}
\DeclareFloatFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\floatsetup[table]{font=tiny}

\linespread{1.40} %1,5 cm linjeavstand (1.25 = 1,5)

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx} %linalgjh
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}

\newcommand\y{\cellcolor{green!10}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\input{listingsSetup}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{}
\rhead{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{7mm}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@algocf@start}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
}{%
  \rule{0.2\textwidth}{\z@}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}{%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{titlepagecolor}{cmyk}{1,.60,0,.40}
\definecolor{namecolor}{cmyk}{1,.50,0,.10} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pdfpages} % To insert pdf pages
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\title{Bibliography management: \texttt{natbib} package}
\author{Share\LaTeX}
\date { }

% --------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\includepdf[pages=-]{MasterThesis/Images/Frontpage.pdf}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents 

\hbadness=1000000000
\newpage

\rhead{Page \thepage \ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\newpage

\input{1.Introduction.tex}
\input{2.Introblock.tex}
\input{MasterThesis/Conclusion.tex}
\newpage

\bibliography{sources}
\newpage


% APPENDICES --------------------------------------------------

\appendix
\lhead{Appendix A}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix A}
\includepdf[pages=-,clip,pagecommand={\section*{\textcolor{white}{Appendix 
A}}\label{appA}},linktodoc=true]{MasterThesis/Images/InterviewRequest.pdf} 

\lhead{Appendix B}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix B}
\includepdf[pages=-,clip,pagecommand={\section*{\textcolor{white}{Appendix 
B}}\label{appB}},linktodoc=true]{MasterThesis/Images/Informants.pdf} 

\lhead{Appendix C}

\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix C}
\includepdf[pages=-,clip,pagecommand={\section*{\textcolor{white}{Appendix 
C}}\label{appC}},linktodoc=true]{MasterThesis/Images/InterviewGuide.pdf} 


\end{document}
```

Additional side question:

Problem: Go to code location in pdf not working

In Sharelatex, when clicking the arrows which are supposed to take me to the PDF location based on my position in the code, nothing happens. The reversal however, does not pose any issues. I can double click anywhere in the PDF and it takes me to the relevant code.

Has anyone encountered this issues using the arrows? Is there any other way to easly toggle from the code location to the PDF ?

Answer (score 2):

With `pagecommand`, the `\label` is set on every page, so the last one is used.
You already clear the page before invoking `\includepdf`, so you can set the label before `\includepdf` too: Use

```
\cleardoublepage\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendix C}
\label{appC}% Add the label here
\includepdf[pages=-,clip,pagecommand=,linktodoc=true]{MasterThesis/Images/InterviewGuide.pdf}
```

If you omit `pagecommend=,` your header will not appear on the included pages.

Comment: That trick did the magic! Thanks for the help!